# setting the selected row programmatically for a DataGridRow (not by using the index!)

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I have a form with a `DataGridView` on it, that gets populated in the form's `Constructor` from a `DataSource` using a data adapter (`AdsDataAdapter`). It shows people's `first name`, `surname` and `reference number` (which is the primary key of the underlying table in the database). The rows in the `DataGridView` however are ordered by the `surname` field (by using the `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT` statement that gets passed to the data adapter).

After the `DataGridView` is populated, I want to be able to type a `surname` in a `TextBox`, and have the `DataGridView` navigate to the first row where the first letters of the `surname` matches what the user types.

How do I go about doing this navigation?

Comment: @user5129991: Are you aware that you can select an answer for your question?

Answer (score 1):

**The "navigate" solution**

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i=0;i<theDataGridView.RowCount;i++)
  {
    if (theDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["surname"].Value.ToString().StartsWith(textBox1.Text))
    {
      theDataGridView.CurrentCell = theDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["surname"];
      // optionally
      theDataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = theDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
      break ;
    }
  }
}
```

**The "Filter" solution**

First, bind your DataTable to the DataGridView via a BindingSource.

```
BindingSource theBindingSource = new BindingSource() ;
theBindingSource.DataSource    = theDataTable ;
theDataGridView.DataSource     = theBindingSource ;
```

Then set the Filter property of the BindingSource in the TextChanged event:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  theBindingSource.Filter = "surname LIKE '"+textBox1.Text+"%'";
  // if no match : Cancel filter
  if (theDataGridView.RowCount==0) theBindingSource.Filter = "" ; 
}
```

Comment: I've suggested an edit to address some bugs in your code and also suggested the addition of `theDataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = theDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;` to your *Navigate* method, as it will more visually fulfill the OP's requirement: "*navigate to the first row* [...]".

Comment: Setting the selected row as first visible one is perhaps more user friendly. Using lots of DataGridViews, I never did that when selecting the CurrentCell and never had any feedback to display it as first visible row. In the proposed modification, you introduced a "%"  between the "LIKE" and the TextBox.text, but I didn't keep it, because the request was rather "StartsWith" than "Contains".

Comment: Ah, good catch on the extra `%`, I must have been looking at the other answer when I was testing that in the filter. Sorry about that.